# constructing a model on a subset of a dataframe

Tags: r, linear-regression

consider for example the "iris" dataframe which is installed with main setup of R :

```
names(iris)
# [1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species" 
levels(iris$Species)
# [1] "setosa"     "versicolor"   "virginica"
```

now I construct three models without attaching the "iris":

```
t1=lm(iris$Sepal.Length ~ iris$Sepal.Width + iris$Petal.Length , data=iris)

t2=lm(iris$Sepal.Length ~ iris$Sepal.Width + iris$Petal.Length , data=iris[iris$Species=="setosa",])

t3=lm(iris$Sepal.Length ~ iris$Sepal.Width + iris$Petal.Length , data=iris , subset = (iris$Species=="setosa"))
```

now i think `t2=t3<>t1` but R says `t1=t2<>t3`. why I'm wrong?!!

now I construct again my models but this time with attaching the "iris":

```
attach(iris)

t1=lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length , data=iris)

t2=lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length , data=iris[iris$Species=="setosa",])

t3=lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length , data=iris , subset = (iris$Species=="setosa"))
```

now me and R both think: `t2=t3<>t1`. but again I'm confused because of the effect of attaching on model! I think first set of models is equivalent to second set of models, but R says no! thanks.

Comment: First note: you don't need to put iris$ before each variable name when a function uses data=iris.  e.g., `tm1=lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length, data=iris)` works.

Comment: Second, I think it is better to create subsets outside out of the model statements. e.g., `setosa <- subset(iris, subset = Species == "setosa")` then you can run the linear model on the subset.

Comment: so is putting iris$ before each variable have some effects on models? @Twitch_City

Comment: It is just overriding the `data=iris` argument. When you use `data=iris`, `lm()` knows to look for `Sepal.Length` and the others inside the `iris` dataframe.

Comment: Also, my other recommendation is to never use `attach()`, it just leads to bad habits.

Comment: a nice point, but by this question I'm trying to learn how does R really works with data. @Twitch_City

Comment: what does `<>` mean?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are actually asking then, but these are equivalent: `t3a <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length, data=iris, subset = (Species=="setosa"))
setosa <- subset(iris, subset = Species == "setosa")
t3b <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length, data=setosa)`

Comment: @BryanGoggin in VBA, not equal to or != or in some languages ~=.

Comment: Oh, I get your point. Yes, in the first block, the `iris$` is what is actually changing the model for `t2`. Basically, you are trying to give a subset to the `data` argument, then overwriting that when you use `iris$`.  Just remove the `iris$` from `t2` in the first block and it will match the other subsetted output.

Comment: please read: I understand your Answer much better than your recent comment and I think it contains the main point: first block is a `lm` on vectors and the second block is a `lm` on a `dataframe`. the first block have nothing to do with `dataframe` anymore. so as you said filtering on t2 in first block doesn't works because the model doesn't see `dataframe` (and ofcourse the filter on it). but filtering on t3 works as this example: construct 4 vectors x,y,z with same length and arbitrary w. then `lm(z~x+y, subset=(w>10))` is different from `lm(z~x+y, subset=(w<10))`.  thanks. @Twitch_City

Comment: In both blocks you are running `lm()` on a dataframe... You should always use `data = X`, and never use `X$` in your calls to `lm()`. Then R looks for the dataframe X and, after that is found, looks at your `subset` argument to partition the dataframe. If you use `X$`, R doesn't run the subset argument at all since you didn't properly pass it a dataframe but just that one vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a scoping issue. If you do:

```
t1=lm(iris$Sepal.Length ~ iris$Sepal.Width + iris$Petal.Length , data=iris)

t2=lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length , data=iris[iris$Species=="setosa",])

t3=lm(iris$Sepal.Length ~ iris$Sepal.Width + iris$Petal.Length , data=iris , subset = (iris$Species=="setosa"))
```

You get the desired result.

```
 coef(t1) == coef(t2)
 (Intercept)  iris$Sepal.Width iris$Petal.Length 
    FALSE             FALSE             FALSE 

 coef(t2) == coef(t3)
 (Intercept)  Sepal.Width Petal.Length 
    TRUE         TRUE         TRUE
```

When you say `iris$Sepal.Length`, R already knows where to look for that value. The `subset` argument is thus redundant and R ignores it. As mentioned in the comments, there is no need to use `foo$bar` when `data = foo` is supplied, and this situation looks to be a good example of why not to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Two methods for conducting a linear model on a subset:

## Creating the subset manually

```
setosa <- subset(iris, subset = Species == "setosa")
t1 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length, data=setosa)
```

## Using the subset argument in `lm()`

```
t2 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length, data=iris, subset = Species == "setosa")
```

`t1` and `t2` are equivalent. However, if you use `iris$` in the `lm()` call, `R` ignores what is passed to `data` (and possibly `subset`), since you are explicitly giving the vectors to the function rather than the dataframe.  This is an incorrect way to use `lm()`.